# Custom HTML JQuery Form not working in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms

I created a form that uses JQuery and AJAX to submit a form and swap page content without refreshing the page. This works perfect when tested outside of WordPress. When I add to wordpress and fill out the form, the page just refreshes to a blank form.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //When the form is submitted...
        $('#savvyform').on('submit',function(e) {
            //Send the serialized data to mailer.php.
            $.ajax({
                url:'mailer2.php',
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                type:'POST',
                success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000); //=== Show Success Message==
                },
                error:function(data){
                $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000); //===Show Error Message====
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
            //$.post("mailer.php");
            //Take our response, and replace whatever is in the "form2"
            //div with it.
            $('#form1').hide();
            $('#form2').show();
        });
    });
```

Here is the HTML Form

```
<form id="savvyform" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
        <table>
        <tr><td>First Name*:</td><td><input type="text" name="formfname" autofocus required></td><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="formaddress"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name*:</td><td><input type="text" name="formlname" required></td><td>City:</td><td><input type="text" name="formcity"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>E-mail*:</td><td><input type="email" name="formemail" required></td><td>State/Province:</td><td><input type="text" name="formstate"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phone*:</td><td><input type="text" name="formphone" required></td><td>Zip:</td><td><input type="text" name="formzip"></td></tr>

        <tr><td colspan="2">Brief description of  goals:</td><td>Country:</td><td><input type="text" name="formcountry"></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><textarea name="formgoals"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onMouseDown="javascript:swapContent('form2');"></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you including this in separate file or in the footer of same page?

And try using full url to mailer2.php file.

Try

get_stylesheet_directory().'/mailer2.php'

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use full path to the mailer2.php 
if its in the theme folder use:

```
url:<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>'/mailer2.php'
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

if its in the root directory use this :

```
url:<?php echo site_url(); ?>'/mailer2.php'
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url

the above method work only if this script in a .php file, if you add this script in a .js file you can directly add the url to the file like:

```
url:'http://www.sireurl.com/path/to/mailer2.php'
```

Comment: I tried as     `code`url:<?php get_template_directory() ?>.'mailer2.php' and    `code`url:get_template_directory().'mailer2.php' neither work as it doesnt display the address in source just the code

Comment: check the updated answer, if you are using `get_template_directory()` function you need to use `echo` to print the value, it only return the url doesn't print it like `the_content ()`

Comment: I tried this and even added the permanent path with no results.